# Can we modify function prototype inside function?

Tags: c

I am having declaration in C as follows :

```
void abcd(int , char);

void main()
{
    extern void abcd(char);
    abcd (q);
}
```

Is it okay to have such code implemented?
How C will allow us to code like this?
function call to abcd() will take 'q' as a char or as an integer?

Comment: even if that was possible, that would lead to undefined behaviour... because the function cannot unpack its arguments depending on how the caller defined them.

Comment: A function declaration means "there is a function somewhere that looks like this". If you have two different declarations it means that one of them is incorrect. There is no reason for the language to do anything sensible when you are lying to it.

Comment: You cannot "modify"it but if there's some reason, you can cast the function to a different type and call it like that.

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function: (regardless of what Visual Studio might allow) those signatures are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Notice that all the valid signatures have a return type of `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry I overlooked the C instead C++ tag (C++ stuff removed). I think this should do in C:

```
void abcd_c(char x){};
void abcd_i(int x){};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 #define abcd abcd_c
 abcd('t');
 abcd('e');
 abcd('s');
 abcd('t');
 #undef abcd

 #define abcd abcd_i
 abcd(123);
 #undef abcd
 }
```

You just use `#define/#undef` to select wanted behavior in parts of code

Answer (score 8):

[C11 6.2.7p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7p2)

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have **compatible type**; otherwise, **the behavior is undefined**.

`void abcd(int, char);` is an external declaration that says `abcd` takes `int` and `char` as arguments. It is not compatible with `extern void abcd(char);`, which says that the same function now takes just one `char` as an argument.

If I read the standard correctly, this is not a constraint error, so a compiler need not produce even a *warning* for this. It is still broken and wrong.

Comment: GCC (and likely clang) will warn / error on this if you use a stricter set of compilation options

Comment: @cat naturally.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in C you cannot do this. Actually the compiler will not even bother to "cry" as this is syntactically correct. But on the other hand this is wrong and won't execute. Personally I pay very much attention at mistakes that compiler accepts but disrupts the execution.
Generally speaking you have to declare this function above main , with the proper argument , character in this situation. Because C will look for the declaration of this particular function and she won't find it.
In C++ it's easy as you can overload functions and compiler would understand just from the type of arguments.